# How to use weighted attributes in predicting by IBK?

Tags: weka, knn

I am working on predicting a numeric valued column using IBK. I have two data set: train data set and test data set. Since my predicted values using the following code don't satisfied me I want to weight each column to make the predicted values more acceptable.

After searching, I found out that the only scheme in Weka that does take attribute weights into account is naive Bayes. I wonder is ther any way to weight attributes using naive Bayes and then use the output of naive Bayes (weighted attributes) in IBK?

```
try{
        IBk knn = new IBk();
        String[] options = new String[2];
        options[0]= "-F";
        options[1]= "-E";
        knn.setOptions(options);
        knn.setKNN(100);
        knn.setCrossValidate(false);

        trainData.setClassIndex(trainData.numAttributes()-2);

        testData.setClassIndex(testData.numAttributes()-2);

        knn.buildClassifier(trainData);
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainData);
        eval.evaluateModel(knn, testData);
        System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n\n", false));

        for(int i=0; i<= testData.numInstances()-1; i++)
        {
            double c = knn.classifyInstance(testData.instance(i));

            System.out.println(c);

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine the weight of the attributes? It seems to me that one of the feature filtering algorithms in Weka would be more suitable for that.

Comment: Yes, I want to determine the weight of the attributes. Could you please explain more about the feature that you are talking about? Thanks.

Comment: I'm talking about [this](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Performing+attribute+selection). Running one of these algorithms will give you a (ranked) listed of attributes which you can use to assign weights.

Comment: I've offered a 50-point bounty for an answer!

Comment: @AlexR I will implement this, because I need it by myself. Hang on, I will be back.

Comment: @AlexR Yesterday, I tried to implement the attribute weighted KNN described in http://www.d.umn.edu/~deoka001/AttributeWKNN.html and http://www.d.umn.edu/~deoka001/downloads/K_Nearest_Neighbor_Algorithm.pdf (Paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.49.3282). The result is that it generally does not improve the accuracy. I would prefer that you instead use PCA as a pre-processing step (easy in WEKA). Essentially, the result of a PCA filter can be interpreted as an attribute weighting approach since multiple attributes from the original data are weighted and condensed.

Comment: @AlexR What confused me about the approach is especially the gradient step (K_Nearest_Neighbor_Algorithm.pdf, slide 20, "W_k = \alpha * Error * V_k" for each attribute weight with "Error = Actual Class - Predicted Class". This step does not make any sense in my opinion, especially when training on multi-label datasets. If I have 100 possible classes and assigning class 1 to an item which is class 100 in reality, error=100-1=99. But in fact, the difference of predicted and real class ordinal is typically not correlated with the severity of classification error.

Comment: I have not read the paper, but perhaps was the author limiting the scope to only binary classes represented as 0 or 1?